# Why are fields missing from a Stored Procedure after verifying the database in a Crystal report?

Tags: database, crystal-reports

I have a Stored Procedure in a crystal report which has more than 10 fields before verifying the database.
Once I verify the database by entering the parameters for the Stored Procedure, it directs me to the map fields window. Here, the map button is greyed out. Once the database is verified, the fields which were present earlier under that Stored Procedure, are missing. Can someone help me out as to why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: I think it shows only the differences, doesn't it?

Comment: No, all the fields, new and old are displayed.

Comment: Did you checked if the stored procedure still returns those fields? If it doesn't, so that is why Crystal will not show them.

Comment: While executing the stored procedure, it just says Command(s) completed successfully. Why am i not able to view the fields?

Comment: May you show your store procedure content and its execution?